# MySQL - Multiple set on LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I've a `table_name` like this:

```
No | Name | Inserted_Date | Inserted_By
=====================================
```

and then I've file name.csv like this

```
no,name
1,jhon
2,alex
3,steve
```

I want to load these file `table_name` using syntax like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'name.csv' INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
???
```

the question is, what should I put on `???` so I can store data like this:

```
No | Name  | Inserted_Date | Inserted_By
=====================================
1  | jhon  | sysdate()     | me
2  | ales  | sysdate()     | me
3  | steve | sysdate()     | me
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I do not understand if columns `inserted_date` and `inserted_by` already exists in your table. If no than you can add them before runing `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'name.csv' INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@no, @name)
set
  no = @no,
  name = @name,
  inserted_date = now(),
  inserted_by = 'me'
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this will do it:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'name.csv' INTO TABLE table1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
    SET inserted_date=CURRENT_DATE(), inserted_by='me'
```

Take a look at the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Insert bulk more than 7000000 record in 1 minutes in database(superfast query with calculation)

```
mysqli_query($cons, '
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
    INTO TABLE tablename
    FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
    LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (isbn10,isbn13,price,discount,free_stock,report,report_date)
     SET RRP = IF(discount = 0.00,price-price * 45/100,IF(discount = 0.01,price,IF(discount != 0.00,price-price * discount/100,@RRP))),
         RRP_nl = RRP * 1.44 + 8,
         RRP_bl = RRP * 1.44 + 8,
         ID = NULL
    ')or die(mysqli_error());
$affected = (int) (mysqli_affected_rows($cons))-1; 
$log->lwrite('Inventory.CSV to database:'. $affected.' record inserted successfully.');
```

RRP and RRP_nl and RRP_bl is not in csv but we are calculated that and after insert that.

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do that using the load data command in mysql. The data has to be in your input file.

If you are on Linux, it would be easy enough to add the additional field data to your input file using sed or similar tools.

Another alternative would be to upload your file and then run a query to update the missing fields with the data you desire.

You could also set up a trigger on the table to populate those fields when an insert happens, assuming you want to use the mysql username value.

Answer (score -1):

```
LOAD DATA Local INFILE 'name.csv' INTO TABLE table1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
    SET inserted_date=CURRENT_DATE(), inserted_by='me'
```

Comment: How is this different from the 4-year-old answers already posted to this question? It does not add any value.

Comment: This is a different answer. This one is using `LOAD DATA` **`Local`** `INFILE` instead of just `LOAD DATA INFILE`.