# Cannot find error in this SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using PHP to execute this query and I get a syntax error and cannot figure out where the error is.   I try commas or no commas between the SET commands and still get this error.  Can someone spot it for me?  I apologize but I can't figure it out and need a second set of eyes.

```
Error during import: LOAD DATA INFILE '/zzz/tmp/php0saZKS' INTO TABLE TD16 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (recid,creatorid,@createdate,groupid,fname,minitial,lname,morf,@dateofbirth,homephonenumber,dlnumber,ssnumber,occupation,hoursperweek,address1,city,state,zip,doh,annualsalary,planstartdate) SET createdate = STR_TO_DATE(@createdate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'), SET dateofbirth = STR_TO_DATE(@dateofbirth, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'); 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET dateofbirth = STR_TO_DATE(@dateofbirth, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is that you are repeating the `SET` command when you should be using a comma like so:

```
LOAD data infile '/zzz/tmp/php0saZKS' INTO TABLE td16 fields terminated BY ',' 
optionally enclosed BY '"' lines terminated BY '\r\n' ignore 1 lines (recid, 
creatorid, @createdate, groupid, fname, minitial, lname, morf, @dateofbirth, 
homephonenumber, dlnumber, ssnumber, occupation, hoursperweek, address1, city, 
state, zip, doh, annualsalary, planstartdate) 

SET
   createdate = str_to_date(@createdate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'),
   dateofbirth = str_to_date(@dateofbirth, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i');
```

*EDIT: A related question: [MySQL - Multiple set on LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530971/mysql-multiple-set-on-load-data-infile)*