# How to skip first row in .csv while import and add a row while export?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, export

I am just trying to skip the first row while importing a three-column .csv
I did see some complicated solutions which I believe don't fit in my code.
Can I get some help?
here is my the code for importing CSV:

```
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                
                if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
                    
                    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
                    
                    while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                        
                        $value_age = $column[0];
                        $value_no = $column[1];
                        $value_benefit = $column[2];
                        
                        $rider_id = $_POST['rider_id'];

                        $insertId = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT into shield_rider_value set company_id='" . $company_id . "', policy_id='" . $policy_id . "', rider_id='" . $rider_id . "', rValue_age='" . $value_age . "', rValue_no='" . $value_no . "', rValue_benefit='" . $value_benefit . "'");
                        
                        if (!empty($insertId)) {
                            echo'<script> window.location.replace("?p=policy&pId='. $policy_id .'&alert=3"); </script>';
                        } else {
                            echo'<script> window.location.replace("?p=policy&pId='. $policy_id .'&alert=0"); </script>';
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I also want to add a title row to the export file which is more complex for me.
export code I am using is:

```
 $rider_id = $_GET['rider_data_download'];

    $rider_list = $con->query("SELECT * FROM shield_riders where rider_id = $rider_id");
    while($row = $rider_list->fetch_assoc()) {

    $filename = "$row[rider_name].csv";
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

    $query = "SELECT rValue_age, rValue_no, rValue_benefit FROM shield_rider_value WHERE rider_id=$rider_id ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    exit;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the [`LOAD DATA` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so use **only prepared statements with parameters** and most problems go away.

Comment: set a variable $ i = 0; before the while loop  and only insert values if $i is bigger than 0 at the end of the wjhile loop increas $i +1, so you ncan skip easily the first row.

Comment: @nbk thanks. changing to prepare...

Comment: @GMB can I assign columns separately in that?

Comment: @nbk i do use that $i++ while adding data in bulk but here i am confused with $column[0].
Do I use $i with $value_age as $value_age[$i] or with $column[0] as $column[0][$i] ?

Comment: no $i is only a place holder to check if the first row can be inserted, you could use it to chekc how many rows you have, but it is nt needed for something else, as far as your code goes, A boolean would work also.

Comment: Load Data can insert into bigger tables see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531336/5193536

Answer (score 0):

I just found the simple solution for skipping the first row of CSV while import:

```
fgetcsv($file); // adding this before while loop.
```

Maybe this can help someone else too!